# Which Thread will be notified if we call notify with object reference

Tags: java, multithreading

As we know `wait()` and `notify()` is defined in `Object` class because monitor will be set on `Object` not on particular thread of that object, so my question is if we write

```
MyObject mo=new MyObject();
Thread t1=new Thread(c);
Thread t2=new Thread(c);
try {
t1.wait();

c.notify();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

which thread will be notify if we call notify using object reference as above Thread t1 or t2.

Comment: None, because the threads were not started yet. Anyway, what's `c`?

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: If you consult the documentation you will find your answer, not that it's even comprehensible why you're asking or what on earth your code is meant to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *same* object for `wait` and `notify`.  If `x` is any `Object`, and thread `t1` executes this:

```
x.wait();
```

then when another thread later uses this on the *same* `Object`:

```
x.notify();
```

then `t1` will be notified, because it's the thread waiting on `x`.  (This is assuming no other threads have done a `wait` on the same object.  If there is more than one thread waiting, the system will pick one.)

Your mistake is in trying to use `wait` on a `Thread` object:

```
t1.wait();
```

This is legal, because you can `wait()` on any `Object`, and a `Thread` is an `Object`.  But it's pointless, and not the normal way to do things.  It's more normal to declare some other object that is used as the monitor that two threads use to synchronize.  But that other object can be anything.  It could be a simple `Object`:

```
Object synchronizePoint;
```

but often it's some other object that's one of the main objects that all the threads are working on, making it a convenient object to use for synchronization without having to declare a new one.